# In 18.04 opencv waitKey loop exit immediately

Tags: 18.04, video, opencv

I have compiled and linked example from [Example source](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html)
Successfully. In Ubuntu 16.03 begin to work after entering user to group video.
I did the same in 18.04 but program exits immediately.

I try to debug code and discovered that problem is waitKey.
If i change

```
if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
```

to

```
waitKey(30);
```

It works, but not correctly. How to correctly change the code?

Comment: "It works, but not correctly." - please elaborate. If I read the documentation [1] correctly, `waitKey` waits for x ms on key press. If no key is pressed it returns -1 and loop in your example breaks...
[1] https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously API implementation changed from 2.4.9 to 3.2 so example needs to be corrected.

In ver. 2.4.9 when no key pressed in x ms time returns -1

In ver.  3.2  when no key pressed in x ms time returns 255

So code for both versions for me looks like this:

```
int k; // key
k=waitKey(30);
if( 255!=k && -1!=k )  
   break;
```